# Skip fragments onBackPressed (add/hide)

Tags: android, android-fragments, fragmenttransaction, onbackpressed, fragment-backstack

I am using fragmentTransaction to proceed through fragments, it looks like this:

```
        FragmentManager fm = oldFragment.getFragmentManager();
        FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fm.beginTransaction();
        fragmentTransaction.add(oldFragment.getId(), newFragment, tag);
        fragmentTransaction.hide(oldFragment);
        fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(tag);
        fragmentTransaction.setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_FADE);
        fragmentTransaction.commit();
```

Having several fragments I want to skip some of them when going back.

Example:

> Frag1 -> (Press Next) -> Frag2 -> (Press Next) -> Frag3 -> (Press Back) -> Frag1

This solution works when I use **replace** instead of **add and hide**

```
getFragmentManager().popBackStack(
    tag, 
    FragmentManager.POP_BACK_STACK_INCLUSIVE);
```

Reference` [Skip some fragments onBackPressed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25875975/skip-some-fragments-onbackpressed)

But in my case the skipped fragments are shown for a brief moment. How can I make it as if the fragments in between were never there?

Comment: I don't know if I'm understanding it right but did you try to use fragmentTransaction.remove(FRAGMENT_YOU_NEED);

and do it twice

Comment: Still has the animation problem

Comment: ok but the fragments were removed? its just the animation?

Comment: Yes it works correctly, the fragments are removed, but the intermediate fragments are shown for a brief moment

Answer (score 0):

I use this function to remove fragments tell me if I helped .

```
public static void removeFragment(FragmentActivity activity) {
    try {
        FragmentManager supportFragmentManager = activity.getSupportFragmentManager(); // getFragmentManager();
        FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction();
        fragmentTransaction.setCustomAnimations(R.anim.slide_down, R.anim.slide_up);
        fragmentTransaction.remove(supportFragmentManager.getFragments().get(0));

        try {
            fragmentTransaction.commit();

        } catch (Exception e) {
        }
        supportFragmentManager.popBackStack();

    } catch (NullPointerException exception) {
        exception.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: There is no getFragments() method. (min api is 19, I am not using support)

Comment: can you replace that to supportFragmentManager.findFragmentByTag("TAG") ? check if this works